# What is the purpose of "けど?" at the end of this sentence

Tags: sentence-final-particles

I'm confused by the けど at the end of this sentence, I know  it means 'but', though the sentence is a question and when I try to translate it, I can't seem to make it fit.

「大事な話がある、っていうのに送信先に田中ちゃんが入ってない時点で、それ以外考えられないと思うけど？」

My translation is: "I think, even though there are important stories, in the time when Tanaka chan was not in the destination, everything except that was unthinkable?"

That doesn't seem right to me and I'm getting more confused by the sentence ending as a question with kedo.

Answer (score 0):

「大事な話がある、っていうのに送信先に田中ちゃんが入ってない時点で、それ以外考えられないと思うけど？」= 「・・・、それ以外考えられないけどどうなのよ？ or 私にはそれ以外考えられないけど、その点あなたはどう反論できるの？」

"けど？" = "けど・・・？" = "けど、どうなんですか？" = "xxx, but I'm afraid I have different understanding of it. How do you argue against my understanding?"